# How to render subNavigation components of shopify polaris

Tags: reactjs, shopify, polaris

I need to render one component at a time but some how my subNavigation routes does not work
it works for Navigation routes but does not show me subNavigation items, I've also tried it with the help of react routes but it gives me conflicts with the shopify routes
Here are my routes

Navigations:

```
      <Navigation location="./">
        <Navigation.Section
          items={[
            {
              url: '/setup',
              icon: SettingsMajor,
              label: 'Setup App',
              onClick: props.changeSetupTabToActive
            },
            {
              url: '/manage/freeshipping',
              label: 'Manage',
              icon: ManagedStoreMajor,
              subNavigationItems: [
                {
                  url: '/manage/freeshipping',
                  icon: ShipmentMajor,
                  label: 'Free Shipping Bar',
                  onClick: props.changeFreeShippingBarTabToActive
                },
                {
                  url: '/manage/freesample',
                  icon: AddProductMajor,
                  label: 'Free Samples',
                  onClick: props.changeFreeSampleTabToActive
                }
              ],
            },
            {
              url: '/support/faq',
              label: 'Support',
              icon: CircleInformationMajor,
              subNavigationItems: [
                {
                  url: '/support/faq',
                  icon: QuestionMarkMinor,
                  label: 'FAQ\'s',
                  onClick: props.changeEmailUsTabToActive
                },
                {
                  url: '/support/emailus',
                  icon: InviteMinor,
                  label: 'Email Us',
                  onClick: props.changeFaqsTabToActive
                }
              ],
            },
          ]}
          separator
        />
      </Navigation>
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this approach for onClick:

```
onClick: () => window.location.assign("/manage/freeshipping"),
```

and if you want to do something more than navigate, then you can write this:

```
onClick: () => {
    window.location.assign("/manage/freeshipping");
    //do something more here like:
    //props.changeFreeShippingBarTabToActive();
},
```

I hope this helps